# Dashboard is not displayed as graph in Lightning home page, but as link

Tags: lightning, dashboard, lightning-home-page

I am trying to embed a dashboard in a Lightning home page. It is shown, but only as a link to the dashboard. The actual contents are not shown.

When you google this problem, a suggested cause is that the dashboard is too big for the allocated space. But this particular dashboard only consists of a single graph, one column wide. It is very small. I have also added a much bigger report graph just above the dashboard, that is displayed without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, it looks like a home page component that has a width of 1/3, is judged not to be large enough to display a dashboard, no matter how narrow that dashboard is.

A home page component with a width of 2/3 or full will display a dashboard.